# Stretch To with Copy Location bone constraints not working properly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I have 3 bones and 4 empties. I am trying to make each bone stretch to one of the empties where each bone has a copy location constraint to one of the empties, but for some reason it's not working, not sure why. I can change the value of the Rest Length manually but this is not what I want as I want it to work correctly without manual adjustments as this will be written in a python script.

As shown below is a screenshot of the problem and highlighted the desired output.

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things here, uncheck connected on each bones' parenting as it messes with the copy locations, and then set the bone tips to the same position as the empties in edit mode before resetting the stretch to length.

Uncheck this checkbox on each bone:

[image]

I would suggest making the stretch to target the next bone rather than the empty, as that will make it easier to set the rest positions/lengths with reset.

Fixed blend:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please provide screenshots and steps to follow through the .blend file I provided? As I'm kind of lost.

Comment: @Tak added a picture of the checkbox and a fixed blend.